# phpMyAdmin error: "Data truncated for column 1"

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file into phpMyAdmin, and I don't understand the error "Data truncated for column 1." Since the field id is to be auto-incremented, I left it out at first, but I got an error concerning the field count. I then tried putting just a semicolon in front of everything, thinking that MySql would see a NULL value and auto-increment all the rows. Not so. Instead I got an error that the 'id' isn't an integer, so I assigned ids for all the rows. I also made sure that the character encoding was consistent - utf8.

Here's the structure of the table:

```
Field       Type            Collation   Atributes   Null    Default Extra
id          int(6)                                  Não     None    AUTO_INCREMENT
data        date                                    Não     None
apto        int(3)                      UNSIGNED    Sim     NULL
descricao   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci         Não     None
rec         float(11,2)                             Sim     NULL
pag         float(11,2)                             Sim     NULL
```

Here´s the first row that gave the error (the name has been changed to protect the innocent):

```
1;2012-01-03;101;Fred - janeiro;90.00;
```

I have a semicolon at the end because the last field has a value of NULL

Comment: Will it import without the auto_increment? Did any rows get imported or did it fail on the first one?

Comment: I turned of auto_increment and got the same error, and yes, it failed on the first one.

Comment: try leaving the id null, and adding a semicolon at the end (after the last null):  ;;2012-01-03;101;Fred - janeiro;90.00;;

Comment: That didn't work either. It's lunchtime here, so I won't be responding to anything for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the most elegant solution, but just say no to CSV with phpMyAdmin. Using macros and regular expressions in my favorite text editor (TextPad), I converted my CSV file into an SQL file, and imported it without any problem.